# Maximum trailing zeros of the path

Tags: dynamic-programming, number-theory

Problems:

A table with $n$ rows and $m$ columns is filled with number from $1$ to $100$ (duplication allowed). The player starts at $(1, 1)$. He can only move right or down. The goal is to reach $(n, m)$. Let $S$ be the product of numbers the player has met along the way to $(n, m)$. Find maximum number of trailing zeros of $S$ if the player moves optimally.

What I think about this problem is to use Dynamic Programming. $S$ is equal to $2^x\times5^y\times other\ primes$ so the answer should be $min(x, y)$ but finding maximum $x$ or $y$ is not optimal. $min(x, y)$ instead should be maximized. Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each cell $(i,j)$, store the set of possible pairs $(x,y)$'s.

Now, DP by scanning row-major from top row to bottom row, for each cell $(i,j)$, only needs to consider $(i,j-1)$ and $(i-1,j)$ (if any), either choose or not to choose $(i,j)$. So from the stored set in $(i,j-1)$ and $(i-1,j)$, compute $(i,j)$'s set easily.

Try to finish the above idea in details. And then code it in your favorite programming language will quickly improve your DPing skill.

Comment: My idea is to let $DP(i, j ,k)$ equals to the maximum 2s at $(i, j)$ with $k$ 5s. The transition would be $DP(i, j, k) =  max(DP(i-1, j, k-P_5), DP(i, j-1, k-P_5)) + P_2$ for arbitrary $k$ where $P_2$ and $P_5$ are number of 2s and 5s in cell $(i, j)$ respectively.  Thanks for your help. It really help me solve this problem.